# Changing Fontmarker Size Expression in QGIS 3.28 using Python Console

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, vector-layer, qgis-python-console, rule-based

I am currently working on a geology and mineral occurrence map in QGIS 3.28. I have a vector rule-based layer in which mineral deposits are classified with different symbols. Some of these symbols consist of only a simple marker (with the size depending on an attribute defined in the size expression), while others use both a Fontmarker and a simple marker.

I am attempting to change only the Fontmarker size expression programmatically using the Python console, but I am encountering an issue where nothing happens after I run the code.

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
# Layer name and new size expression
layer_name = 'M.Base metals'
new_size_expression = 'CASE WHEN "size" = 1 THEN 2 WHEN "size" = 2 THEN 4 WHEN "size" = 3 THEN 6 END'

# Get the layer by name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

# Check if the layer is valid
if not layer:
    print(f"Layer '{layer_name}' not found.")
else:
    # Get the renderer
    renderer = layer.renderer()

    # Check if the renderer is rule-based
    if isinstance(renderer, QgsRuleBasedRenderer):
        # Iterate through each rule
        for rule in renderer.rootRule().children():
            # Check if the rule contains a Font Marker symbol layer
            if rule.symbol().symbolLayer(0).layerType() == 'FontMarker':
                print("Processing rule:", rule.label())  # Debugging

                # Update the font marker size expression
                rule.symbol().symbolLayer(0).setDataDefinedProperty(
                    QgsSymbolLayer.PropertySize, QgsProperty.fromExpression(new_size_expression)
                )

        # Refresh the layer to apply changes
        layer.triggerRepaint()

    else:
        print(f"The layer '{layer_name}' renderer is not rule-based.")
```

After running the above code, I expect the Fontmarker size expression to change, but nothing seems to happen. Can someone please help me understand what I might be missing or doing wrong in my Python script?

[image]